# Can I have a copy of a file in every worker in Spark?

Tags: file, apache-spark, hdfs

I am writing some files in `hdfs` with `saveAsTextfile` and i was wondering if i could read them and have a copy in each worker.
Reading them with `sc.TextFile` creates a `RDD`, so i can have only a partition in each worker. 
Is there any other way to do it? Maybe read it somehow to driver and broadcast it?

Answer (score -2):

Edit:
If the file is small enough, you should download the file to edge node and pass it to all executors using --py-files/--files (pyspark/spark respectively).

Ignore this old comment:
`Yes generally we use broadcast if you want to have a small data available in all the executor nodes.`